# How to find records where we have both values in child records

Tags: mysql

I have a posts table where tags are saved in another table. And the structure is as following.

**POSTS table**

| ID | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Something related to AUSTRALIA and CRICKET |
| 102 | Something related to INDIA and CRICKET |
| 103 | Something related to CRICKET ALONE |
| 104 | Something related to INDIA ALONE |

**TAGS table**

| ID | POSTS_ID | TAG_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 101 | CRICKET |
| 1002 | 101 | AUSTRALIA |
| 1003 | 102 | CRICKET |
| 1004 | 102 | INDIA |
| 1005 | 103 | CRICKET |
| 1006 | 104 | INDIA |

Is there any way we can get the posts_id based on the combination of tags ? For example, I would like to get the posts_id where tags CRICKET & INDIA is present.

**expected result:**

| ID | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | Something related to INDIA and CRICKET |

the table have approximately a million records. So the query has to be optmised.

Its a bit tricky for me to solve this. I would be really thankful if someone can help me on this.

Comment: JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY, COUNT(DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this:

```
Select POSTS.* From POSTS 
INNER JOIN TAGS on POSTS.ID = TAGS.POSTS_ID
where TAGS.TAG_NAME LIKE '%INDIA%' OR TAGS.TAG_NAME LIKE '%CRICKET%'
```

you can modify where clause, this is based on what I understood from your question

Comment: But I need to get records where the child tags contain INDIA and CRICKET.
Not INDIA or CRICKET

Comment: actually this condition can only be satisfied like this because none of your child tags contain both INDIA and Cricket. so using AND will not yield those results.

Comment: also you are can modify where clause like this: WHERE POSTS.TITLE LIKE '%INDIA%' AND POSTS.TITLE LIKE '%CRICKET%'

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have found the answer.

```
select posts.id, posts.title from posts
 join (
   select posts_id from post_tags
   where TAG_NAME in ('INDIA','CRICKET')
   group by posts_id
   having count(DISTINCT(TAG_NAME)) > 1
 ) as c_post_tags
 on posts.id = c_post_tags.posts_id
```

And I have made the post_tags.TAG_NAME as an INDEX. so that the performance is much faster.

Thank you all for your efforts

Comment: *`having count(DISTINCT(TAG_NAME)) > 1`* You'd use not `> 1` but `= 2` (the amount of values in a list). If the list contains more than 2 values then `> 1` will produce excess rows in the output.